# Refining list based on checkboxes and dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've got an unorganized list, populated with items that have several data attributes.

```
<ul>
    <li data-category="option1" data-green="t" data-blue="f" data-soft="t">Product 1</li>
    <li data-category="option1,option3" data-green="f" data-blue="t" data-soft="t">Product 2</li>
    <li data-category="option4" data-green="f" data-blue="f" data-soft="f">Product 3</li>
    <li data-category="option5" data-green="f" data-blue="t" data-soft="t">Product 4</li>
    <li data-category="option1" data-green="t" data-blue="f" data-soft="f">Product 5</li>
    <li data-category="option1,option3,option4" data-green="f" data-blue="f" data-soft="t">Product 6</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to refine this list based on a couple of selection criteria. These criteria can be chosen via one dropdown selection and multiple true/false checkboxes.

```
<div id="refine">
    <select class="category">
        <option value="showall">Show all</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" value="green">Green
    <input type="checkbox" value="blue">blue
    <input type="checkbox" value="soft">soft
</div>
```

The amount of true/false checkboxes is dynamic so more than three can be added in the future.

Also, a product can be available in multiple categories, if so the data-attribute `category` has multiple values seperated with a comma.

I'm trying to refine the list based on the selected options on top.

```
$('#refine').on('click','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
    var inputvalue = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is( ":checked" )){
        $('li[data-'+inputvalue+']').each(function(){
            var attributValue = $(this).attr('data-'+inputvalue+'');
            if(attributValue != 't'){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
    else{
    //Show all (this still needs to check what other options are still selected)
        $('li[data-'+inputvalue+']').show();
    }
});

$('#refine').on('change','.category', function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("li[data-category]").each(function(){
        var data_categ = $(this).attr('data-category');
        if (data_categ.indexOf(selectedValue) < 0){
            $(this).hide();
        }else{
            //Show all (this still needs to check what other options are still selected)
            $(this).show();
        }
        if(selectedValue == 'showall'){
            //Show all (this still needs to check what other options are still selected)
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm stuck at the part where I want to show the parts I've just hidden. When I select "Show all" in the dropdown, or uncheck a checkbox, all the elements are shown again. Disregarding the other selecting options.

How can I prevent this?

So consider the following case:
I selected `option 3` and `soft`. I changed my mind about the `option 3` selection and switch this back to `Show all`. Now I want to show all categories, but only the ones that have `soft` as a data attribute. But in my code it shows all list items again on `Show all` disregarding the fact that I still have `soft` selected.

The same goes for selecting multiple checkboxes and deselectin one.

Can anyone assist on this?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x42ey9t7/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```js
var $products = $('li'),
  $checks = $('#refine input[type="checkbox"]'),
  $category = $('#refine select.category');
$('#refine').on('change', 'input, select', function() {
  var $lis = $products,
    category = $category.val(),
    $checked = $checks.filter(':checked');

  if (category != 'showall') {
    $lis = $lis.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('category').indexOf(category) >= 0;
    });
  }

  if ($checked.length) {
    $checked.each(function() {
      $lis = $lis.filter('[data-' + $(this).val() + '="t"]');
    }).get();
  }

  $lis.show();
  $products.not($lis).hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refine">
  <select class="category">
    <option value="showall">Show all</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" value="green" />green
  <input type="checkbox" value="blue" />blue
  <input type="checkbox" value="soft" />soft
</div>

<ul>
  <li data-category="option1" data-green="t" data-blue="f" data-soft="t">Product 1</li>
  <li data-category="option1,option3" data-green="f" data-blue="t" data-soft="t">Product 2</li>
  <li data-category="option4" data-green="f" data-blue="f" data-soft="f">Product 3</li>
  <li data-category="option5" data-green="f" data-blue="t" data-soft="t">Product 4</li>
  <li data-category="option1" data-green="t" data-blue="f" data-soft="f">Product 5</li>
  <li data-category="option1,option3,option4" data-green="f" data-blue="f" data-soft="t">Product 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is close. However, when I select multiple checkboxes I only want products that comply to ALL these criteria. So when Green and soft are both selected, I ONLY want to show products that have BOTH these attributes, not one out of two matching.